# Codeigniter dompdf : Invalid Character Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

When I try to print a pdf I get this error:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: DOMException

Message: Invalid Character Error

Filename: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/application/helpers/dompdf/lib/html5lib/TreeBuilder.php

Line Number: 3191

Backtrace:

File: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/application/helpers/dompdf/lib/html5lib/TreeBuilder.php
Line: 3191
Function: setAttribute

File: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/application/helpers/dompdf/lib/html5lib/TreeBuilder.php
Line: 1493
Function: insertElement

File: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/application/helpers/dompdf/lib/html5lib/Tokenizer.php
Line: 2456
Function: emitToken

File: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/application/helpers/dompdf/lib/html5lib/Tokenizer.php
Line: 1102
Function: emitToken

File: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/application/helpers/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php
Line: 470
Function: parse

File: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/application/helpers/dompdf_helper.php
Line: 26
Function: loadHtml

File: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/application/controllers/admin/Estimates.php
Line: 136
Function: pdf_create

File: /home/ireto/domains/ireto.be/public_html/madicbelgium/index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once
```

This is my code on line :3191
->

```
private function insertElement($token, $append = true) {
    $el = $this->dom->createElementNS(self::NS_HTML, $token['name']);

    if (!empty($token['attr'])) {
        foreach ($token['attr'] as $attr) {
            if (!$el->hasAttribute($attr['name']) && preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/u", $attr['name'])) {
                $el->setAttribute($attr['name'], $attr['value']);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($append) {
        $this->appendToRealParent($el);
        $this->stack[] = $el;
    }

    return $el;
}
```

Comment: the only thing which is needed but missing, is the `name` of your attribute @ `setAttribute`... (most likely you have an invalid name for your attribute...)

Comment: @sintakonte i dont really get what the problem is , im using the same script on my invoice payments and if i do the same handling everything is working

Comment: again - what is the name of your attribute where this error occurs? I'm pretty sure you have an invalid name for your attribute - so post it - because otherwise nobody is able to help you ..

Comment: pro-1 is the tname of my atribute @sintakonte

Comment: not sure if this is the correct one - take a look @my sandbox example ... this error only gets thrown if you declare an invalid atttribute name http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/603567881b7f29e6afe4bae862535847291e8285  - if you remove the `1` in front of the attribute it works well - so i'm assuming your attribute name is something else, take a look @your exception you should be able to see the exact error - as i've shown in my example

Answer (score 0):

if you face an error like `An uncaught Exception was encountered` the best way is, to actually catch the exception, because you get the answer for your error in your `Exception`

the following code snippet should do what i mean

```
private function insertElement($token, $append = true) {

    try
    {
        $el = $this->dom->createElementNS(self::NS_HTML, $token['name']);

        if (!empty($token['attr'])) {
            foreach ($token['attr'] as $attr) {
                if (!$el->hasAttribute($attr['name']) && preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/u", $attr['name'])) {
                    $el->setAttribute($attr['name'], $attr['value']);
                }
            }
        }
        if ($append) {
            $this->appendToRealParent($el);
            $this->stack[] = $el;
        }



        return $el;
    }
    catch (DOMException $e)
    {
        echo '<strong>Errormessage:</strong>'.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();

    }
}
```

if you have an error now, you should see the exact information in order to fix this error, something like the following occurs:

```
Errormessage: Invalid Character Error

#0 [...][...](7): DOMElement->setAttribute('1pro-1', 'someValue')
#1 {main}DOMException Object
```